# ajax form with multiple submit buttons and values

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am working in wordpress and I have an html form with two submit buttons with same classname and different value. I am passing the submit button clicked value through ajax and show it on the screen. Now my problem is that only first submit button value goes through and second submit button value never gets to show on the screen. Kindly guide and below is my code.

Code

```
<form id="mydispimage" action="" method="post"><select id="category" style="width: 250px; background-color: lightgrey;" name="category">
<option disabled="disabled" selected="selected" value="">Select category</option>
<option value="Cutie Pie">Cutie Pie</option>
<option value="Chubby">Chubby</option>
<option value="Dimples">Dimples</option>
</select>
<input class="displayimage" name="displayimage" type="submit" value="star1" />
<input class="displayimage" name="displayimage" type="submit" value="star2" /></form>
```

Jquery

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $(".displayimage").click(function (e) { //form is intercepted
    e.preventDefault();
    //show timer
    jQuery("#timer").css("display","block");
jQuery("#participate").css("display","block");
var vote= jQuery(".displayimage").val();
alert(vote);

 //$("#timer").show(slow);
        //serialize the form which contains secretcode
       // var sentdata = $(this).serializeArray();
//var vote = 1;
        //Add the additional param to the data        
        var sentdata =({

            action: 'displaymyimage',
            foo: vote
        })

        //set sentdata as the data to be sent
        $.post(yes.ajaxurl, sentdata, function (res) { //start of funciton
            //$("#myresult").append(res.l);
            //alert(res);
            $("#myresult").html(res);
 //$.parseJSON(data);
            return false;
        } //end of function
        ,
        'json'); //set the dataType as json, so you will get the parsed data in the callback
    });  // submit end here

    });
```

Comment: This is not WordPress related, but your issue appears to be `var vote= jQuery(".displayimage").val();` You are grabbing the first element that has that class, not the current element.

Comment: wow thanks you are absolutely right... infact this wordpress and I have used this html in page edit and this ajax is enqueued in wordpress from function.php file... so thanks I changed var vote= jQuery(".displayimage").val();
 to var vote= jQuery(this).val(); and boom it worked ... thanks